# Elastic Beanstalk Docker App fails after "Restart App Servers"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to test a very simple docker app in Elastic Beanstalk. However I've encountered a very strange problem where my application fails with a "502 Bad Gateway" after I do "Restart App Servers" from within my EB application environment.

I'm doing the following...

- eb init "test-app"
- Create a simple Dockerfile...

{code}

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y apache2

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

{code}

- eb create "test-app-dev-123"

The application is created and deployed successfully, and responds correctly to web requests.

However if I try restarting the the app server, from the EB console, or from the aws cli command line, it appears to work, however all requests then fail with the 502 Error.

The only way to recover is to re-deploy the environment.

While it's in the failing state, if I use "eb ssh" to connect to the host, I can see that the docker container is constantly trying to restart. It starts, and then almost immediately stops again. However from the host I can manually start the container (with docker run...) and it works fine.

I've tried to make my example as simple as possible. There is nothing in my eb application other than the single Dockerfile.

I've done more investigation, and this looks like a bug in EB. I've downloaded the logs, and this is where it looks like it's starting to go wrong...

```
time="2016-07-18T01:51:08.119354030Z" level=error msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device 3244...ef18: invalid argument" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:10.414373171Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:968d...5a9 cleaned up" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:11.023279947Z" level=error msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device e140...53366: invalid argument" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:13.310053346Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:968d...65a9 cleaned up" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:13.911371884Z" level=error msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device c3f...6f: invalid argument" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:25.369515769Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/containers/2c98ce28854f returned error: You cannot remove a running container 2c98...bb34. Stop the container before attempting removal or use -f" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:25.414283268Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/images/3d39763a8ca1 returned error: conflict: unable to delete 3d39763a8ca1 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 2c98ce28854f" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:25.414503066Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/images/df34b0ea0bfb returned error: conflict: unable to delete df34b0ea0bfb (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:25.414735070Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/images/c67665a031d2 returned error: conflict: unable to delete c67665a031d2 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images" 
time="2016-07-18T01:51:25.414947068Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.23/images/cf62323fa025 returned error: conflict: unable to delete cf62323fa025 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images" 
time="2016-07-18T02:35:45.291715871Z" level=info msg="Container 2c98...1bb34 failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force" 
time="2016-07-18T02:42:53.063530940Z" level=info msg="Container 2c98ce...e1bb34 failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
```

This, to me, looks like some kind of incompatibility between EB and Docker.

Comment: Are you using Load Balancer in this stack?

Comment: I'm testing with a single instance at the moment, however it always seems to use a load balancer.

Comment: Ok The problem is happening because your Docker is not passing the health check in the ELB, thats why it is restarting. Try one thing change the health check in you ELB from http to TCP and then try to launch.

Comment: Thanks @error2007s I managed to get it working by changing Health Reporting system type to "Basic" in the console.

Comment: @user1751825 you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Actually I'm still having some issues. It fixed it for a while, but eventually started giving errors again.

Answer (score 0):

You should either set the Health Report system to Basic, or setup the load balancer using .ebextensions as described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html